# how to compare wildcard string with javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to compare two strings one being wildcard with javascript.

I'm checking whether this string is found on web page or not.

`<div class="Modal A2aModalStep Step">` and retrieving it in variable k.

and want to compare it.

like

```
if ( k == "<div class=\"Modal A2aModalStep Step\">") {
  //some code
}
```

But the problem is that class name changes it's pos randomly like sometimes `step Model A2aModalStep` or `A2aModalStep Step Model` etc...

so, I want to compare

```
if ( k == "<div class=\"[Model|A2aModalStep|Step] [Model|A2aModalStep|Step] [Model|A2aModalStep|Step]\">"){
  //some code
}
```

I'm using this javascript in imacros, so can't use predefined function. must be in pure javascript comparison using operator and variable

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Why not use multiple compare statements?

Comment: like ? any example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the webpage itself, use DOM methods to look for if an element with those 3 classes exists:

```
const div = document.querySelector('.Modal.A2aModalStep.Step');
if (div) {
  // some code
}
```

Selector strings don't care about the order of classes.

If you're not able to use any DOM methods, I suppose you could use a regular expression instead: after matching the `"`, lookahead for `[^"]*\bModal\b`, and for `[^"]*\bA2aModalStep`, and for `[^"]*\bStep`:

```js
const check = str => /div class="(?=[^"]*\bModal)(?=[^"]*\bA2aModalStep)(?=[^"]*\bStep)/.test(str);
console.log(check("<div class=\"Modal A2aModalStep Step\">"));
console.log(check("<div class=\"Modal Step A2aModalStep\">"));
console.log(check("<div class=\"Modal A2aModalStep\">"));
```

Comment: #updated org que.... 
forgot to mention that cant use any pre defined functions as i'm using this in iMacros... so need it in pure js

Comment: You should really parse the HTML using an HTML parser if at all possible, but if that's not an option, I suppose you could use a regular expression

Comment: i had compared it with value of k (<div class=\"Modal A2aModalStep Step\">) but its giving me true every time? i think something is wrong

Comment: Were you expecting that to give you `false` instead? Why, doesn't it contain all 3 classes you're looking for?

Comment: i have two pages, one page contain this class and 2nd dont.... checked on both page and both giving me true. 

i want it to be true if all three class is contained in any random order.... if not than false

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? For what input were you expecting the code to give `false` instead?

Comment: if var k == null or undefined than it need to be false

Comment: Ok, then just check if `k` is null or undefined first.

Comment: so simple, it worked, thanks... btw i think coding is not cup of my tea ;_; thankx anyways